# onRowClicked for react-datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

onMeetingTitleClick is working when i use onClick but it only works for that specific column.

I'm trying to get it working for the entire row using onRowClicked but i don
t think i'm doing it right. Any ideas?

```
const MeetingsTable = ({ meetings, onMeetingTitleClick }) => {
  ...

  const columns = [
    {
      name: 'Title',
      cell: row => (
        <div data-tag="allowRowEvents">
          <div aria-hidden="true" onClick={e => onMeetingTitleClick(e, row.id)}>
            {row.name}
          </div>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  const onRowClicked = () => (result.map(result => (e => onMeetingTitleClick(e, result.id))));

  return (
    <DataTable
      columns={columns}
      data={result}
      onRowClicked={onRowClicked}
    />
  );

... Omitted other values
```

Reference lib: https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to complete this by using the following

`const onRowClicked = (row, event) => { onMeetingTitleClick(event, row.id); };`

https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component#readme